# I am having some trouble in this python exercise

Tags: python, sockets

I have a problem with this exercise, here is the exercise:

Change your socket program so that it counts the number
of characters, it has received and stops displaying any text after it has shown 3000 characters. The program should retrieve the entire document and count the total number of characters and display the count
of the number of characters at the end of the document.

Original Code:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
data = mysock.recv(512)
if len(data) < 1:
break
print(data.decode(),end='')
mysock.close()
```

MY CODE:

```
import socket
url=input("Enter a URL :\n")
count=0
host_name=url.split("/")[2]
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
    cmd=('GET url HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode())
    mysock.send(cmd)
except:
    print("Enter a valid URl")
exit()


while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    count=count+len(data)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

My output:

```
Enter a URL :
http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 May 2019 10:29:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error Message " 400 Bad request"

Can anyone help me, Thank you

Comment: Surely you need to pass the actual path, not the string "url", in the GET request? The question implies you previously had a working version of this, though.

Comment: The first exercise was to allow the user to put his own url, this is the extension of the question.

Comment: How can i pass a string with GET?

Comment: But again, how did you do this in the previous version? If the user could put in his own URL, surely you must have included that in the GET.

Comment: @DanielRoseman THIS IS THE FIRST QUESTION, ALSO I PASTED THE ORIGINAL CODE ABOVE PLEASE CHECK                                               
 "Change the socket program socket1.py to prompt the user
for the URL so it can read any web page. You can use split('/') to
break the URL into its component parts so you can extract the host
name for the socket connect call. Add error checking using try and
except to handle the condition where the user enters an improperly
formatted or non-existent URL."

Comment: You are requesting the string "url" here ```cmd=('GET url HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode())```. If you are on Python 3, you can change it to ```cmd=(f'GET {url} HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode())``` and it will work as expected.

Comment: @accdias Thankyou for the comment, but I tried it didn't work

Comment: Try passing "Host:" on your get request. Something like this: ```cmd=f'GET {url} HTTP/1.0\nHost:{host_name}\n\n'.encode()```. I tried to execute the commands using telnet and the remote hosts answered only when I specified the "Host:" as well.

Comment: @accdias I tried but still same problem

Comment: @FsJO, check the answer I posted. I guess the problem was with the ```encode()```.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

url = urlsplit('http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt')
host = url.hostname
path = url.path

request = f'GET {path} HTTP/1.1\nHost: {host}\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result.decode('utf-8'))
```

And here is the output of above code:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Content-Length: 167
 Connection: keep-alive
 Keep-Alive: timeout=15
 Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 08:49:50 GMT
 Server: Apache
 Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 19:05:04 GMT
 ETag: "a7-526172f58b800"
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET

 But soft what light through yonder window breaks
 It is the east and Juliet is the sun
 Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
 Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

Edit: here is your original code corrected:

```
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

url = urlsplit(input("Enter a URL: ").strip())
count = 0
host = url.hostname
path = url.path
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    print(f'Connecting to {host} and fetching {path}')
    s.connect((host, 80))
    cmd = f'GET {path} HTTP/1.1\nHost: {host}\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
    s.send(cmd)
except:
    print("Enter a valid URl")
    exit()

while True:
    data = s.recv(512)
    count += len(data)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())

s.close()
```

And here is the output I'm getting using the above code:

```
Enter a URL: http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
Connecting to www.py4inf.com and fetching /code/romeo.txt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 167
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 15:30:16 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 19:05:04 GMT
ETag: "a7-526172f58b800"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet 
is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

Comment: Thankyou ,the next question was to use urllib but this question was about to let the user enter the url and without using urllib

Comment: @FsJO, I know that. You just need to insert the input part. I'm using ```urlib.parse.split()``` just to separate the ```hostname``` from the ```path``` because you need that to use with ```socket```.

Comment: Also notice that you have ```exit()``` in the wrong level of indentation in your original code.

Comment: thankyou so much mate, I really appreciate your help. Perfect

Comment: @FsJO, if possible, mark my answer as accepted. That way you can help others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, running on Python 3

```
import socket

url = input("Enter a URL :")
try:
    host_name = url.split("/")[2]
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
    s = 'GET '+url+' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
    cmd = s.encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)
except:
    print("Enter a valid URl")
    exit()

count=0
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    for c in data:
        count += 1
    if count > 3000 or len(data) < 1:
        break
    #print(data.decode())
print(count)
mysock.close()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Also, don't name variables after builtins, like `str`. This shadows the builtin and could lead to problems down the road. I've changed the name of the `str` variable to `s`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and for me it works (Python3):

```
import socket

url = input("Enter - ")

try: 
    word = url.split("/")
    host = word[2]
    print("The host: ", host)

    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((host, 80))
    cmd = ("GET" + url + "HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)

except:
    print("Not a url")

count = 0

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    for c in data:
        count += 1
    if len(data) < 1 or count > 3000:
        break
print(count)
mysock.close()
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket

# ask user for the url
# get the host name from the url
user_url = input('Enter a url: ')
host_name = user_url.split('/')
host_name = host_name[2]

# create the socket
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# create a connection to the host:web server
my_socket.connect((host_name, 80))

# encode the http request to UTF-8
cmd = ('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n').encode()

# send the http request
my_socket.send(cmd)

# receive 512 bytes at a time
# decode this data to Unicode and print it
data_count = 0
while True:
    data = my_socket.recv(512)
    data_count += len(data)
    # once ALL data has been retrieved break
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    # stop printing when data shown > 30000
    if data_count < 3000:
        print(data.decode())

# close socket
my_socket.close()

# print total data count
print(data_count)
```